# SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000 Error In Storing string value

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing issue in saving string values in one of the fields of my domain

My Domain is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    Long id
    @NotNull
    String uuid
    @NotNull
    String firstName
}
```

I am pulling the data from my main mysql database and saving it into another database.

```
       resultSet = statement.executeQuery(userQuery)
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                User user = new User()
                user.id = resultSet.getLong("a.id")
                user.uuid = resultSet.getString("a.uuid")
                user.firstName = resultSet.getString("b.first_name") // exception occurs here
                userRepository.save(user)
            }
```

Some of my data is getting saved but when data from my main database contains user with

**firstname = ऋषभ (Name in Hindi Language)** then it throws exception.

Note - Only essential codes i mentioned here query execution database connection everything is running fine only facing issue in setting data in user.firstName only when my query result contains string with different language.

Comment: What's your table collation?

Comment: url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/reporting_db_1?autoreconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false

Comment: i did not set any collation i am just using default settings

Comment: Any sensible server should default to UTF-8 in 2022 but it's something you need to verify. Having a non-Unicode collation like `latin1` is a possible explanation for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY first_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: I can't speak Hindi but you should be aware that `_bin` collations don't take language features into account and, for instance, can cause `WHERE user = 'Admin'` not match `admin`.